# New tag modal is not positioned optimally when tag description is too long

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching

When hovering over a tag with a long description, the tag modal window is not positioned in an optimal way and simply disappears at the top of the window:

[image]

I would have probably expected it to be placed to the right of the tag or simply to have its description shortened.

Working with `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` and `Google Chrome Version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

Comment: The new tag modal is horrible. If scrolling down the screen with the mouse wheel. I now have tag boxes flashing out containing hundreds of characters of text -- none of which I want to see. The irony is we lost the Question Title mouseover text because we needed to save bandwidth and it took too much -- now we have flying tag boxes that contain an equal amount of text. The Question Title summary was far more useful than the tag-flyouts. I would gladly trade the tag-flyouts to get the Title mouseover summary back. Why do you all think we want pop-outs? They are annoying.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to display tag overlays anymore: how many seconds do we need to wait with the mouse over the tag before anything appears?

Comment: imnsho the optimal way would be 20000 dp's to the right of my visible screen

Comment: We don't need any of this on the frontpage, and it is already in the sidebar anyway!

Comment: So, we have already have a maximum length for these excerpts and for what? So that they don't get tested? Isn't the whole point of this to ensure that everything can be made to accommodate all legal excerpts? And now we have multiple places where legal-yet-too-long excerpts can occur. “Never tested anything.” seems to be the theme in this redesign. (I'd like to request theming support so I can try out different themes. This one is getting annoying.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be *improved* in the next build.  The behavior here is definitely bad, but the fix might not be that satisfying.

The problem we're running into here is a set of extremes.

- The text here is very long.  It's only three characters off the max length.
- The popup has the "Manage Subscription" button, which you have because you're currently subscribed to the tag via the SE.com question filter integration.
- The window is very short, only 656px tall.

This runs into some design decisions:

- Text is untruncated in the modal.  There are very few places on the site where you can read the full short description of a tag and I didn't want to truncate here.  This would severely cut down the utility of the popup on pages like `/tags`.
- The font is bigger, there's more whitespace, and there's the speech bubble thingy.  The watch/ignore buttons are bigger.  These are all here to improve usability and readability.
- The "Manage Subscriptions" button exists.  In an ideal world, we would have already moved tag watching to the new system by now, but things are taking time, so we added that button for anyone who would have the "Unsubscribe" button in the old dialog.  There wasn't really space next to the RSS icon, so we just gave it a full button placement.
- We show the modal above the tag if there isn't space below.

Incidentally, you can recreate this problem for this tag on the old modal if you cranked your window down to 400px.

The solution I'm deploying is to just not show the modal above the tag if there's not space to view it above and below.  In that case, there's at least something you can do to scroll down a bit to see the rest.  Showing on the side is a decent option, but then we need to worry more about width on responsive design, thinking about four directions instead of just two.  I'm hoping that this is rare enough of an issue that it doesn't have to come to that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This will indeed look better having it truncated at the bottom of the page, as I can scroll to see it completely. I'll probably suggest an edit of the `scala` tag description to shorten it. Concerning the page size, I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one using a 720p screen ;p